# How to turn Time Ranking data into a "Timeline" with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data below

```
        Agent   Rank    START   STOP    CODE
        Joey    52      11:30   11:45   BRK_Break1
        Joey    53      17:30   17:45   BRK_Break2
        Joey    57      14:15   15:15   BRK_Lunch
        Joey    152     09:40   19:00   CONT_Shift
```

which is a persons "status" throughout the data. The logic needs to be that there is one line for each "period" of time so it creates one contiunal "timeline" based upon the rank (lower = higher priority) so it looks like below

```
Agent   Start   Stop    Code
Joey    09:40   11:30   CONT_Shift
Joey    11:30   11:45   BRK_Break1
Joey    11:45   14:15   CONT_Shift
Joey    14:15   15:15   BRK_Lunch
Joey    15:15   17:30   CONT_Shift
Joey    17:30   17:45   BRK_Break2
Joey    17:45   19:00   CONT_Shift
```

Any ideas how this can be achived? Ideally I would like to restrict the use of staging tables and do this through a CTE or maybe some self joins but not sure where to start?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly in what way the time line is based on "rank", you could get those results by simply working out where the start and end times intersect

Comment: IF there is a conflict the item with the lowest rank should take priority. E.G If Cont_Shift rank was 1, we would never see any of the other codes in the final data as Cont_shift is from 9:40 to 19:00

Comment: Is the number of possible different types of ranges fixed?

Comment: Is it possible for a lower rank item to be present temporarily? so in your example, could there be a rank 200 item from `10:00` to `10:15`, say?

Comment: there could be but as it's rank is higher (lower priority) it would never make it into the final timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a really good question, answering it was quite hard. first I waited for someone else to solve it, but since that didn't happen, I gave it a try, I discovered a mistake and gave it another try.

it is not pretty, but it seems there are no features in sql supporting the question. So the sql is quite complex. If someone else comes up with a different and better solution, I will be the first to give it a plus.

```
declare @t table (name varchar(10), rank int, start datetime, stop datetime, code varchar(12))
insert @t values ('Joey', 52, '2011-06-21 11:30', '2011-06-21 11:45', 'BRK_Break1')     
insert @t values ('Joey', 53, '2011-06-21 17:30', '2011-06-21 17:45', 'BRK_Break2')         
insert @t values ('Joey', 57, '2011-06-21 14:15', '2011-06-21 15:15', 'BRK_Lunch')     
insert @t values ('Joey',152, '2011-06-21 09:40', '2011-06-21 19:00', 'CONT_Shift')
insert @t values ('Joey',152, '2011-06-22 09:40', '2011-06-22 19:00', 'CONT_Shift')

;with aa as
(
select name, rank, start, 'b' action, code from @t
union all
select name, rank, stop,  'e', code from @t
)
select * from (
select name,start, 
(select min(start) from aa where start > a.start and a.name = name) stop, 
(select code from (select rank() OVER (ORDER BY rank) as rank, code from @t where dateadd(second, 1, a.start) between start and stop and name = a.name) c where rank = 1) code
from aa a
where not exists (select 1 from @t where a.start between start and stop and a.rank > rank and a.name = name)
and exists (select 1 from @t where a.start between start and stop and a.name = name)
) d
where code is not null and 
name = 'Joey'
order by start
```

Comment: Interesting. +1, though it does look formidable. I think there might be an alternative that uses a recursive CTE. I hope to try to find one soon, when I have time.

Comment: This works well, need to understand it fully before I use. Would hate to drag and drop

Comment: What was the error (I see you have changed the code slighly) I am using the previous code and it seems to work fine unless I am missing something?

Comment: The previous version I replaced didn't work for situations where the periods doesn't overlab like 2 different days, use the current version please.